# verify cummulative sum verify property efficiently with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to verify if the sum of the elements (which are non-negativ) of my list isinferior to some values. And I don't want to calculate the the whole sum it is not necessary.(if we prove that the sum of the first element don't respect the property, we stop the computation)

So I would like a LINQ command that verify each element of the cummulative sum is inferior to some value as long as it see that the ineqality  hold.

```
var b = a.Aggregate(new List<int> { 0 }, (ls, x) => { ls.Add(x + ls.Last()); return ls; }).All(x => x < 4);
```

This method doesn't work. All stop when it see that the ith element of the cummulative sum doesn't safisty the property but the whole cummulative sum is compute.

Have you a better way to do that? (I know we can do that efficiently with loop but I want to do that with LINQ)

if I use a loop:

`var s = 0;`

`var b = true;`

`foreach(var x in list)`
`{`
`s=s+x;`
`if(s>4){ b= false; break;}`
`}`

Thank you

Comment: I can not understand what you want.

Comment: Explain what you want, not how you expect to get it. LINQ is a query language. It doesn't verify anything, it *calculates it*. Your code doesn't do that, it looks like an attempt to add items to a list using `.Aggregate` instead of `foreach`

Comment: Re. your edit, if you can show what you want in a loop it might be easier for us to understand and help translate it into LINQ.

Comment: BTW you *don't* need a LINQ expression to calculate sums. An iterator method with  `foreach` loop would work just as well. In LINQ to Objects most operators *are* loops or at least, custom enumerators

Comment: I have always been curious of the overwhelming number of questions that specifically request that it must be a LINQ command. Aside from a subjective opinion that it reads better in some cases, there is absolutely no benefit, and in many cases, it is less efficient, especially when people start the 48+ chains to accomplish a single loop, lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use a LINQ method to do what you want. You can write your own using enumerators and loops. After all, LINQ-to-Objects operations themselves are implemented using loops. For example [TakeWhile](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L618) is implemented as an iterator that loops over the source and yields matching elements :

```
    static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeWhileIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate) {
        int index = -1;
        foreach (TSource element in source) {
            checked { index++; }
            if (!predicate(element, index)) break;
            yield return element;
        }
    }
```

The downside is that this generates a state machine for the iterator and returns all matching elements, whether they are used or not.

You can write your own extension method that calculates the sum in a loop and returns `true` if the loop completes without reaching the limit :

```
public static bool SumBelow(this IEnumerable<int> source, int limit) 
{
    int sum=0;
    foreach (var element in source) 
    {
        sum+=element;
        if (sum>limit)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And use it as an extension method :

```
var isSumBelow = someEnumerable.SumBelow(5);
```

**Why not a generic method ?**

There's no way to specify an operator constraint or an IAddable interface, which is why [Sum()](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L1408) itself is implemented for each type separately, eg :

```
public static int Sum(this IEnumerable<int> source) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    int sum = 0;
    checked {
        foreach (int v in source) sum += v;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

**The functional way**

Passing the accumulator and condition checker as functions can be used to create one generic, reusable method that can work with any transormation and condition :

```
public static bool AccWithinLimit<T>(
                        this IEnumerable<T> source, 
                        Func<T,T,T> accumulator,
                        Func<T,bool> terminator, 
                        T seed=default) 
{
    T total=seed;
    foreach (var element in source) 
    {
        total = accumulator(element,total);            
        if (terminator(total))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This can be used to check for partial sums with integer arrays :

```
var myArray=new []{1,2,3};
var limit = 5;
var totalBelowLimit = myArray.AccWithinLimit(myArray,
                                  (sum,elm)=>sum+elm,
                                  sum=>sum>limit);
```

Or partial products with a list of doubles:

```
var myList = new List<double>{1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
var limit = 10;
var totalBelowLimit = myList.AccWithinLimit(myArray,
                                  (sum,elm)=>sum*elm,
                                  sum=>sum>limit,
                                  1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use TakeWhile to take items from the list until the sum exeeds some value

```
public void TestTakeWhileCumulativeSum()
{
    int[] numbers = new[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    int maxCumulativeSum = 5;
    int previous = 0;
    var result = numbers.TakeWhile(n => (previous = n + previous) <= maxCumulativeSum);
    Assert.AreEqual(result.Count(), 5);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think it s a good start but i just want to have to boolean and not return a list

Comment: `TakeWhile` is just a loop. All those *counts* though iterate over the entire sequence again and again.